# When is CASE_STRICT generated?

Tags: php, zend-framework, bytecode

I am trying to find an example where PHP 8.1 generates the `CASE_STRICT` opcode.

I found this message from @IluTov: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50366061#50366061

> @Derick When no jump table can be generated.

```php
function foo($value) {
    return match ($value) {
        true => 'foo',
        null => 'bar',
    };
}
```

But that example only generates IS_IDENTICAL/JMPNZ/QM_ASSIGN for each case. I tried different cases and types, but only got either the regular `MATCH` code with jump table or the same IS_IDENTICAL/JMPNZ/QM_ASSIGN combination.

```
0002 T1 = IS_IDENTICAL CV0($value) bool(true)
0003 JMPNZ T1 0008
0004 T1 = IS_IDENTICAL CV0($value) null
0005 JMPNZ T1 0010
0006 JMP 0007
0007 MATCH_ERROR CV0($value)
0008 T2 = QM_ASSIGN string("foo")
0009 JMP 0012
0010 T2 = QM_ASSIGN string("bar")
0011 JMP 0012
0012 RETURN T2
```

What am I missing? When is `CASE_STRICT` generated?

Comment: If you read a little further, Derick says to try `match ($value + 1)` which does appear to generate that on my machine

Comment: That works! Thank you. How did I miss that.